# docker host rebooted automatically when running docker build/run

Tags: centos, docker, restart

I have installed docker 1.5 at the host centos 6.6 (a VM). I am trying to create an image of centos6. But often times the host VM restarted when I runs "docker build...". Any clue of what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: This is very weird, really frustrating. Anyone see this problem before?

Comment: Is it because of the version of the docker host and the docker image? they are all centOS 6.

Comment: doubt it'd make a difference. Is this a custom image your creating? Why dont you try a trusted image from dockerhub which has centos 6? Try out a sample nginx docker image.

Comment: Have same issue if I just run "docker pull centos:6" and then run "docker centos:6 ls root"

Comment: odd - you might get more info from centos forums possibly.

Comment: I ran into the very same issue with Docker and CentOS 6.5. Have you found the solution?